# Looking for a good GIT solution for Web Project maintained with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, git

In our environment we are serving a combination of asp and asp.net pages on Windows 2003 servers running IIS.  We use Visual Studio to edit the pages via FrontPage extentions.

We really enjoy the ability to make quick edits and save and the web is updated immediately.  Don't worry, we do have a development server where we test all of our changes before moving them to the production server.

We do not want to use the "publish site" option if at all possible.

I have been using GIT for some android (eclipse) projects lately and I'm really enjoying it, so now I would like to use GIT for our web site as well if at all possible.

I've have GitExtentions installed, along with the VS plugin and I have tried Git Source Control Provider.

Keeping with the distributed VC mindset, I'd like to have a repo on my (and each of the developers) PC and commit as necessary.

The problem is, since we are editing via http/frontpage (master mode) the files are not stored locally.

I am wondering if anyone else in this type of environment has implemented a successful GIT workflow.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

My solution isn't necessarily ideal for your situation, given you dont want the extra step of publishing...

I have the files locally in my git repo, and then I manually (via script) push them to the web location.

So I traded the ease of editing deployed files, for the awesomeness that is GIT. For me, I came out like a bandit in that trade.